# How to make lines in Plot Legends wider?

Tags: plotting, legending, style

1.- How to put DASHED lines in the Legend?
2.- How to give Style to {20,Bold} to all "Expressions in Legend?

[image]

(I use LegendMarkSize for make lines wider than default fine style )

```
Plot[{{E^(x/(1/4)), E^(x/(1/3)), E^(x/(1/2))}, {E^(x/1), E^(x/2), 
   E^(x/3), E^(x/4)}}, {x, -5, 0.2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Dashing[0.024], Thickness[0.01]}, {Dashing[0.024], 
    Thickness[0.01]}, {Dashing[0.024], Thickness[0.01]}, 
   Thickness[0.01], Thickness[0.01], Thickness[0.01], 
   Thickness[0.01]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[ "Expressions", LegendMarkerSize -> {39, 6}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 0.15}, {0, 1.15}}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The style for labels in a legend is determined by the option `LabelStyle`. To get the legend markers to match the style of the plot without rescaling, one approach is to use `AbsoluteDashing` and `AbsoluteThickness` to style the plot lines.

```
With[{d = AbsoluteDashing[8], t = AbsoluteThickness[4]}, 
 Plot[{E^(4 x), E^(3 x), E^(2 x), E^x, E^(x/2), E^(x/3), E^(x/4)}, {x, -5, 0.2},
  PlotStyle -> {{d, t}, {d, t}, {d, t}, t, t, t, t},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 0.15}, {0, 1.15}},
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions",
    LabelStyle -> {Bold, 20}, LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 10}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your solution is perfect!. only have to add... {Bold,20} to maintain the axis numbers bigger. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`AbsoluteDash` and `AbsoluteThickness` are helpful in this. In the following I have arbitrarily chosen colours for illustrative purposes (so you can change as desired):

```
leg = {{Red, AbsoluteDashing[5], AbsoluteThickness[2]}, {Green, 
    AbsoluteDashing[5], AbsoluteThickness[2]}, {Blue, 
    AbsoluteDashing[5], AbsoluteThickness[2]}, {Red, 
    AbsoluteThickness[2]}, {Green, AbsoluteThickness[2]}, {Blue, 
    AbsoluteThickness[2]}, {Purple, AbsoluteThickness[2]}};
fns = {{E^(x/(1/4)), E^(x/(1/3)), E^(x/(1/2))}, {E^(x/1), E^(x/2), 
    E^(x/3), E^(x/4)}};
Plot[fns, {x, -5, 0.2}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 0.15}, {0, 1.15}}, 
 PlotStyle -> leg, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Directive @@@ leg, Flatten@fns]]
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: You´re answer is TOO an SOLUTION FOR ME. I chosed the other because was posted before.

Comment: @MikaIke thanks...that's fine I think Simon Woods is neater (note he flattened your list of expressions which were nested in your code: I flattened in my legend)

Comment: (+1), is there any way to adjust the length of lines in the legend?